# Gradle: How to share common tasks in multiproject build?

Tags: gradle, multi-project

In my root build.gradle file I apply common tasks for all components:

```
apply from: rootProject.file('common/component.gradle')
```

In subproject i define componentTitle:

```
ext {
    componentTitle = 'application1'
 }
```

component.gradle:

```
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': componentTitle
    }
}
```

I am getting error:

```
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> No such property: componentTitle for class: org.gradle.api.java.archives.internal.DefaultManifest
```

Comment: try project.componentTitle or project.ext.componentTitle

Comment: jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.ext.componentTitle
    }
} 
Error: Cannot get property 'componentTitle' on extra properties extension as it does not exist

Comment: jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': project.componentTitle
    }
} Error: Could not find property 'componentTitle' on root project

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that you've applied this common configuration not only to subprojects, but to the root project too, though it doesn't have such a property. To apply it to subprojects only, configuration could be made like so:

```
subprojects {
    apply from: rootProject.file('/component.gradle')
}
```

But even now Gradle won't find the `componentTitle` property if you pass it the way you did (as a part of subproject script body). You need to make a `gradle.properties` file in all subprojects directories and move this property into this properties file, as usual:

```
componentTitle=application1
```

Then Gradle will be able to locate it during the configuration phase

Comment: I had to add fake property componentTitle=fakeValue to root project to avoid > No such property: componentTitle error in root script.

Comment: It's all because you've applied it to the root script, though it doesn't need it. That is the reason to use `apply from` within subprojects closure